# SharePoint2010 Workflow Error

Tags: workflow, error

We just started getting the following errors when trying to run simple "out of the box" workflows. The workflow history shows an Event Type of “Workflow Cancelled” and the description is “Workflow My Test Approval Workflow was canceled by System Account.”

ULS logs show the following error:

> RunWorkflow: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: 
>            at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPNoCodeXomlCompiler.LoadXomlAssembly(SPWorkflowAssociation
>   association, SPWeb web)
>            at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeHostServices.LoadDeclarativeAssembly(SPWorkflowAssociation
>   association, Boolean fallback)
>            at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeHostServices.CreateInstance(SPWorkflow
>   workflow)
>            at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeEngine.RunWorkflow(SPWorkflowHostService
>   host, SPWorkflow workflow, Collection 1 events, TimeSpan timeOut)
>            at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.RunWorkflowElev(SPWorkflow
>   workflow, Collection 1 events, SPWorkflowRunOptionsInternal
>   runOptions)`

Answer (score 0):

For others that are experiencing this issue.  Here is the article that had the fix for this.  This is a known issue with the September 2018 .NET patch updates.  This causes SharePoint out of the box Workflows to stop working. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2018/09/13/after-installing-net-security-patches-to-address-cve-2018-8421-sharepoint-workflows-stop-working/